# Explain the linker flag "-lm"

Tags: dynamic-linking

Could someone explain the meaning of linker flag "-lm". Which library is being represented by the letter "m". If "m" is not a library name what is it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your system, but traditionally, libm is the math library. Here is where you'll find things like trig functions, square root, and other floating point operations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - wish the name was more self-explanatory